# How to get calendar event info in Android when specific event is clicked?

Tags: java, android, events, calendar, onclick

It is possible to get the events within a time range but is it possible to get the event info when user clicks any part in certain events.

For example if Event contains a URI which is linkified is it possible for application to know the source event which was clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`long end = now + search //in millis

Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Instances.CONTENT_URI,
                String.format("%d/%d", now, end));

Cursor c = resolver.query(uri, PROJECTION, selection, null,
                SORT_ORDER);`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The question said its possible to get within a time range but is it possible to get event info when user clicks on calendar info? Also I could not understand what goes into Instances/projection/selection etc., Please let me know.

Comment: static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
        Instances.ALL_DAY,
        Instances.BEGIN,
        Instances.END,
        Instances.COLOR,
        Instances.TITLE,
        Instances.RRULE,
        Instances.HAS_ALARM,
        Instances.EVENT_LOCATION,
        Instances.CALENDAR_ID,
        Instances.EVENT_ID,
        Instances.OWNER_ACCOUNT,
    };

Comment: static final String EVENT_SORT_ORDER = "startDay ASC, allDay DESC, begin ASC";

Comment: String selection = String.format("%s=1 AND %s!=%d",
                Calendars.SELECTED, Instances.SELF_ATTENDEE_STATUS,
                Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS_DECLINED);   These are things i used.

Comment: Thx Kantesh, I was looking for retrieving eventinfo of the event when user clicks on the event in the calendar.

Comment: In which activity you want this info? day activity week activity?